# SQL Server Stored Procedure with Cursor causing error

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursor, encryption-symmetric

I get this error message. Can anyone help me to fix my query? What is the right way to use the cursor?

This stored procedure should fetch data from a temp table and insert it into two different tables. Some of the columns in the temp table like `EID, FN, MN, LN` should be inserted into table `dbo.tblUser`, and the rest of the columns from the temp table should be in the table `dbo.refRoster_Details`.

Please do help me on this matter thanks.

> Msg 16950, Level 16, State 2, Line 22
>   The variable '@MyCursor' does not currently have a cursor allocated to it.
>
> Msg 16917, Level 16, State 2, Line 96
>   Cursor is not open.
>
> Msg 16917, Level 16, State 1, Line 227
>   Cursor is not open.

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_BulkUserInsert]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate1;

        DECLARE @vEID varchar(max) 
        DECLARE @vFirstName varchar(max) 
        DECLARE @vMiddleName varchar(max)
        DECLARE @vLastName varchar(max) 
        DECLARE @vRoleID int 
        DECLARE @vLevelID int 
        DECLARE @vEmployeeTypeID int 
        DECLARE @vBadgeNo int 
        DECLARE @vSAPID int 
        DECLARE @vContactNo int 
        DECLARE @vBirthDate date 
        DECLARE @vProjectID int 
        DECLARE @vManagerID int 
        DECLARE @vSupervisorID int 
        DECLARE @vLocationID int 
        DECLARE @vHireDate date 
        DECLARE @vRollIn date 
        DECLARE @vRollOff date 
        DECLARE @vTimeIn datetime 
        DECLARE @vTimeOut datetime 
        DECLARE @vIsVisa int 
        DECLARE @vIsPassport int 
        DECLARE @vDateAdded date 
        DECLARE @vDateModified date 
        DECLARE @vTowerID int 
        DECLARE @vIsActive int 

            DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR
            OPEN @MyCursor
            SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR


                SELECT TOP 1
                    --columns to push in tblUser
                    EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), CONVERT(varchar, EID)),
                    EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), CONVERT(varchar,FIRSTNAME)),
                    EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), CONVERT(varchar,MIDDLENAME)),
                    EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), CONVERT(varchar,LASTNAME)),
                    --columns to push in roster_detail
                    CAST(ISNULL(ROLEID,'4') as int) ROLEID,
                    CAST(ISNULL(LEVELID,'1') as int) LEVELID,
                    CAST(ISNULL(EMPLOYEETYPEID,'1') as int) EMPLOYEETYPEID,
                    CAST(ISNULL(BADGEno,'1') as int) BADGEno,
                    CAST(ISNULL([SAP ID],'1') as int) [SAP ID],
                    CAST(ISNULL(CONTACTno,'1') as int) CONTACTno,
                    CAST(ISNULL(BIRTHDAY,'1991-01-01') as date) BIRTHDAY,
                    CAST(ISNULL(HIREDATE,'1991-01-01') as date) HIREDATE,
                    CAST(ISNULL(PROJECTID,'1') as int) PROJECTID,
                    CAST(ISNULL(MANAGERID,'1') as int) MANAGERID,
                    CAST(ISNULL(SUPERVISORID,'1') as int) SUPERVISORID,
                    CAST(ISNULL(LOCATIONID,'1') as int) LOCATIONID,
                    CAST(ISNULL(ROLLIN,'1991-01-01') as date) ROLLIN,
                    CAST(ISNULL(ROLLOFF,'1991-01-01') as date) ROLLOFF,
                    CAST(ISNULL(TIMEIN,'1991-01-01') as datetime) TIMEIN,
                    CAST(ISNULL([TIMEOUT] ,'1991-01-01') as datetime) [TIMEOUT],
                    CAST(ISNULL(ISVISA,'1') as int) ISVISA,
                    CAST(ISNULL(ISPASSPORT,'1') as int) ISPASSPORT,
                    CAST(ISNULL(DATEADDED,'1991-01-01') as date) DATEADDED,
                    CAST(ISNULL(DATEMODIFIED,'1991-01-01') as date) DATEMODIFIED,
                    CAST(ISNULL(TOWERID,'1') as int) TOWERID,
                    CAST(ISNULL(ISACTIVE,'1') as int) ISACTIVE
                FROM tblRIRO_TempRosterList
                ORDER BY [SAP ID] DESC

            --OPEN @MyCursor
           FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO
            @vEID, 
            @vFirstName, 
            @vMiddleName, 
            @vLastName,
           @vRoleID,
           @vLevelID, 
           @vEmployeeTypeID, 
           @vBadgeNo, 
           @vSAPID, 
           @vContactNo, 
           @vBirthDate, 
           @vProjectID, 
           @vManagerID, 
           @vSupervisorID, 
           @vLocationID, 
           @vHireDate, 
           @vRollIn, 
           @vRollOff, 
           @vTimeIn, 
           @vTimeOut, 
           @vIsVisa, 
           @vIsPassport, 
           @vDateAdded, 
           @vDateModified, 
           @vTowerID, 
           @vIsActive

           WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
           BEGIN
                PRINT(@vEID)
                DECLARE @IsEID_Exist int = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) FROM tblUser WHERE EID_encrypt = @vEID),0)
                PRINT (@IsEID_Exist)
                DECLARE @Incremental_UserID int = 0
                IF (@IsEID_Exist = 0)
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO tblUser (EID_encrypt, FirstName_encrypt, MiddleName_encrypt, LastName_encrypt)
                    VALUES (
                            EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), CONVERT(varchar, @vEID)),
                            EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), CONVERT(varchar, @vFirstName)),
                            EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), CONVERT(varchar, @vMiddleName)),
                            EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), CONVERT(varchar, @vLastName)))
                    SELECT TOP 1 @Incremental_UserID = @@IDENTITY
                    IF (@Incremental_UserID > 0) 
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO refRoster_Detail (
                                    UserID, 
                                    RoleID, 
                                    LevelID,
                                    EmployeeTypeID,
                                    BadgeNo_encrypt,
                                    SAPID_encrypt,
                                    ContactNo_encrypt,
                                    BirthDate_encrypt,
                                    ProjectID,
                                    ManagerID,
                                    SupervisorID,
                                    LocationID,
                                    HireDate,
                                    RollIn,
                                    RollOff,
                                    TimeIn,
                                    [TimeOut],
                                    IsVisa,
                                    IsPassport,
                                    DateAdded,
                                    DateModified,
                                    TowerID,
                                    IsActive)
                        VALUES(@Incremental_UserID, 
                                @vRoleID, 
                                @vLevelID, 
                                @vEmployeeTypeID, 
                                EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), CONVERT(varchar, @vBadgeNo)), 
                                EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), CONVERT(varchar, @vSAPID)), 
                                EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), CONVERT(varchar, @vContactNo)), 
                                EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'), CONVERT(varchar, @vBirthDate)), 
                                @vProjectID, 
                                @vManagerID, 
                                @vSupervisorID, 
                                @vLocationID, 
                                @vHireDate, 
                                @vRollIn, 
                                @vRollOff, 
                                @vTimeIn, 
                                @vTimeOut, 
                                @vIsVisa, 
                                @vIsPassport, 
                                @vDateAdded, 
                                @vDateModified, 
                                @vTowerID,
                                @vIsActive)
                    END
                END

                FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO 
                   @vEID, 
                   @vFirstName, 
                   @vMiddleName, 
                   @vLastName,
                   @vRoleID,
                   @vLevelID, 
                   @vEmployeeTypeID, 
                   @vBadgeNo, 
                   @vSAPID, 
                   @vContactNo, 
                   @vBirthDate, 
                   @vProjectID, 
                   @vManagerID, 
                   @vSupervisorID, 
                   @vLocationID, 
                   @vHireDate, 
                   @vRollIn, 
                   @vRollOff, 
                   @vTimeIn, 
                   @vTimeOut, 
                   @vIsVisa, 
                   @vIsPassport, 
                   @vDateAdded, 
                   @vDateModified, 
                   @vTowerID, 
                   @vIsActive
           END
           CLOSE @MyCursor
           DEALLOCATE @MyCursor
    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1;
    END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: The best way to deal with this would be to **simply eliminate** that cursor altogether .....

Comment: Ok then maybe that the only way to make this work. but do you have any idea on how should i construct the query for my stored procedure? the idea is i want to fetch or insert the data from my TempTable into another 2 different tables like Table1 and Table2. i just want to get some fetch like 3 to 4 columns from TempTable into Table1 and the rest of the columns from TempTable will insert into Table2. how can i do that without using the Cursor? thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ...  
> DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR
> OPEN @MyCursor
> SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
> ...
> ```

You call `OPEN` before you allocate a cursor to `@MyCursor`. Move `OPEN @MyCursor` AFTER `SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR ...`.

```
SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
...
    ORDER BY [SAP ID] DESC
OPEN @MyCursor
```

But I wonder why yous use a cursor at all for a `SELECT TOP 1` query. A `SELECT @var = col ...` and an `ID @@rowcount = 1` to handle only the case when data was found would do too.